# How to give a folder path in app.config file in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I am creating an application in WPF.

1. In that I am using XML file to store some settings.
2. My app will run for every 10 sec. So it will use that XML file settings.

My issue is in My local system i am calling the XML file as D://Foldername/projectname/test.xml .
But after deployment it is storing in  C://Programfiles/Projectname/test.xml .

So how to give a generic path so that it runs in all the client systems.
I am creating setup file to install in clients systems.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the project properties page.
2. Click on Settings tab.
3. Add a new item called "MyPath". Make it an Application Setting of type String and give it a sensible default path name as value.
4. Reference the value in code with `Properties.Settings.Default.MyPath`.

If you open the applications config there will be a setting called MyPath where you can override the path at runtime.

Comment: Can we use this with click once deployment and how can we include this file in click once .

Comment: If all deployed clients use the same path you write tHat in the settings and then override in app.config on the development computer.

Comment: If the clients need to customize this setting you change it from Application Setting to User Setting and create a user interface where the user can edit the value.

Comment: But I don't  want to give any options to client I am deploying it with Click Once i am just giving a html url to the client like this http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/test.html. IF they download it from this location directly it should run with out any modifications.

Comment: If you write the path clients shall use in tje Settings dialog, they don't need the config file. That value is hardcoded in the exe and will only be overridden if the config file exists.

Comment: @Fayaz, another suggestion is that maybe you can/should provide multiple entries in the properties settings and depends on the environment it's in, it reads the correct one. Of course, you'll need to setup a Environment variable on each of your servers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put the XML file in the same folder as your EXE file and then use `Assembly` to get its current path.

`var cfgPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config"`

**Update**

it's better to name your config file the same with your exe file but with ".config" extension.

Comment: While creating i am adding the XML  file to the setup project after installation it is storing in Program files folder. where the setup  file is storing.

Comment: I made a mistake, please see updated answer. ".config" is better than ".xml" because it tells you it's a config file and also build in c# configuration classes works better with it too.

Comment: @Fayaz, if your config file is stored in the same folder as the exe file, the updated code should work.

Comment: See my concerns below for saving the config in the executable directory. I think the file extension doesn't matter in any point here.

Comment: But XML  file is storing in the same folder of exe and config if we call Lcoation + config . How it will call the XML  file then it will call the config file write?

Answer (score 0):

If you are really using **ClickOnce**, I hardly recommend you to create your own directory for data and configuration files:

```
private static string GetDataDir()
{
    var dataDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
        "YourApplicationName");
    if (!Directory.Exists(dataDir))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dataDir);
    return dataDir;
}
```

The problem with storing the data in the directory of the executable is, that it will be at a different location. While debugging, it will be in you `\bin` directory. When the application is deployed by **ClickOnce**, you gonna have a bad time. The installation directory for a ClickOnce application is created for every version. So if you **EVER** update your application at "customers", all their settings will be lost.